# I always wonder how this dynamic site content index very fast?

Tags: seo, php, mysql

I am new to this field.Actually I am learning PHP/MYSQL.Five min before I asked a question in StackOverflow.And when I googling this suddenly my question appears.How does StackOverflow index very fast in google.I have PHP site which is indexing by google.But not all pages.Seriously How to do that.

[image]